# Tweepy.cursor multiple / OR logic function for query terms

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to search twitter for a finite period of time in the past couple days to pull 2-3 keywords, but I can't seem to figure out how to search multiple terms at once.

There are probably other ways to do this, but I've got a short code using tweepy.cursor. But I can't figure out how to search multiple query terms at once with this? (The example I have is wanting to search **#superbowl** / **superbowl** / **super bowl** all at once) I've tried several things, but the code below seems to return the AND logic statement. I have seen any documentation that helps.

Any help appreciated!

```
import tweepy
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import csv

access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."
consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

csvFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

search_terms = 'superbowl ', 'super bowl ', '#superbowl'

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=search_term,
                       since='2017-02-16', until='2017-02-17',
                       count=10,
                       result_type='recent',
                       include_entities=True,
                       monitor_rate_limit=True, 
                       wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                       lang="en").items():

eastern_time = status.created_at - timedelta(5)
edt_time = eastern_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

csvWriter.writerow([status.created_at, status.user.screen_name.encode('utf8'), status.text.encode('utf-8')])
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Actually think this code works. Also [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878188/search-term-intersection-and-union-using-python-tweepy) points out that you can use OR specifically within the parenthesis, as in `search_terms = ('superbowl OR super bowl OR #superbowl')`

Comment: You're querying using the variable search_term, which hasn't been defined? You've only defined search_termS.

Answer (score 6):

You use tweepy in exactly the same manner as with a single keyword, but the query parameter `q` should have your multiple keywords. For example, to search for tweets containing either the word "cupcake" or "donut" you pass in the string "cupcake OR donut" as the `q` parameter.