# Twitter Scanner w tweepy - Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I was just wondering if it's possible to make a scanner with tweepy - for instance, a while loop that is constantly searching for certain words. I'm a trader and would find it very useful in case there is any breaking news.

Example:

I want to set my scanner to constantly return tweets that have '$DB' in them. Furthermore, I only want to return tweets of users that have > 5k followers.

Any advice or pointers would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit/Update:** As discussed by asongtoruin and qorka, the question asks for new tweets, not existing tweets. Previous edit used `api.search` method which finds only existing messages. The [StreamListener](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html) reads new messages.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

access_token='your_api_token'
access_secret='your_api_access_secret'
consumer_key = 'your_api_key'
consumer_secret = 'your_consumer_key'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            if status.user.followers_count > 5000:
                print '%s (%s at %s, followers: %d)' % (status.text, status.user.screen_name, status.created_at, status.user.followers_count)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_status: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['$DB','$MS','$C'])
```

Comment: thank you! is there a way to do multiple keywords? If i wanted to do '$DB', '$MS', '$C' - looks like I get StopIteration when I try to add them to 'tweets'

Comment: there is, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878188/search-term-intersection-and-union-using-python-tweepy) and the [Search API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) all terms need to be in a *one string* argument, with each term separated by capitalized `OR`: so it would be `q = ('$DB' OR '$MS' OR '$C')`. I'm currently suspended due to rate limiting so couldn't test it, but give it a try :)

Comment: @qorka, my last comment is incorrect, multiple keywords should be *within* one string, I tested with `tweets = ('$DB OR $MS OR $C')` and it works.

Comment: thank you - that works! However, i'm noticing that the code isn't actively scanning for new tweets, but rather printing the older tweets then going to StopIteration. Is that the same case for you as well?

Comment: `api.search` will only look for existing tweets, not new tweets. Also, tweepy can handle rate limits.

Comment: @asongtoruin is there an option to search for new tweets?

Comment: until @asongtoruin offers his insight, I've updated answer to use `StreamListener`

Comment: @downshift bingo. I really appreciate the assistance here; i'm a newb with python (as you can tell) and you just gave me a nice edge in trading. Thank you!

Comment: @qorka, welcome, glad to help. if indeed my answer helped, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. good luck & happy trading!

Comment: @downshift same approach I would've taken, +1

Comment: @asongtoruin good to hear, thanks for your suggestion and feedback.

Comment: @downshift would you happen to know if this would run OK via django?

Comment: I don't know, possibly @asongtoruin may know, or you could reference this in another question.