# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple using "-filter:retweets" in Python

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to Python and I am currently trying to work with some tweets using these key words. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Define the search term and the date_since date as variables
search_words = ("#breastcancer", "Breast Cancer")
date_since = "2020-03-01"    
new_search = (search_words + "-filter:retweets")
new_search
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c3105fd62a2e> in <module>
----> 1 new_search = (search_words + "-filter:retweets")
      2 new_search

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Comment: Is `search_words` a tuple? If so, then the error is correctly pointing out that you cannot concatenate a tuple and a string. What are you *expecting* this line of code to do?

Comment: can you show us what `search_words` contains?

Answer (score 1):

To search for multiple words using tweepy, you should make your search term(s) variable like this:

```
search_terms = ('#breastcancer OR Breast Cancer')
```

credits to this post:
[Search term intersection and union using Python Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878188/search-term-intersection-and-union-using-python-tweepy)